# Как организовать Router php

Tags: router, mvc, php

Подскажите алгоритм, этапы, как лучше сделать такую систему роутинга. Читал много про роутинг но, там все как-то просто реализовано было, без регистрации их. Пытался разобрать framework-и, но все как-то сложно сделано.

Подскажите, с чего начать, или посоветуйте похожую уже готовую систему.

P.S. Прошу не ругать за свой велосипед будущий. :)

Настройки роутеров записаны в следующем виде:

```
 <?php
    return array(
    'home' => array(
       'pattern' => '/',
       'controller' => 'Blog\\Controller\\IndexController',
       'action' => 'index'
    ),
    'hello' => array(
      'pattern' => '/',
      'controller' => 'Blog\\Controller\\HelloController',
      'action' => 'index'
    ),
    'show_post' => array(
      'pattern' => '/posts/{id}',
      'controller' => 'Blog\\Controller\\PostController',
      'action' => 'show',
      '_requirements' => array(
        'id' => '\d+'
      )
    ),
 );

 class Router{
   private $registry;
   private $path;
   private $args = array();

   function __construct($registry){//  список всех роутеров
     $this->registry = $registry;
   }

}
```

Comment: >без регистрации их

В каком смысле без регистрации?

Comment: Почитай вот тут http://habrahabr.ru/post/150267/ Плюс там в конце ссылка есть на тестовый проект.

Comment: Ну, в смысле не заносят их в массив, к примеру, а так просто добавляют к ним слово Controller.php. Типа что-то http://iantonov.me/page/pishem-sobstvennyj-mvc-frejmvork-na-php

Comment: https://elisdn.ru/blog/113/psr7-framework-http - очень подробная инструкция. Всё хорошо объяснено.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать `spl_autoload_register`. 
Проще говоря, автозагрузка классов.
Выглядеть это должно примерно, вот так:
spl_autoload_register("autoloader");

```
function autoloader($class) {
$dirs = array(
'controllers/',
'models/',
'core/'
);

$class = strtolower($class);
foreach ($dirs as $location) {
if(file_exists(__DIR__.'/'.$location.$class.'.php')){
require_once(__DIR__.'/'.$location.$class.'.php');
break;
}
}
}
```

А дальше, через route, делайте проверки..

Answer (score -3):

Я писал свой велосипед и решил эту задачу по своему с использованием регулярных выражений в качестве правил:
1) Создаём правила и загоняем их в глобальную переменную:

```
$GLOBALS['routing'] = array(
    '' => array(
        'controller' => 'CWelcome',
        'action' => 'index'
    ),
    'login' => array(
        'controller' => 'CWelcome',
        'action' => 'login'
    ),
    'logout' => array(
        'controller' => 'CWelcome',
        'action' => 'logout'
    ),
    'admin$' => array(
        'controller' => 'CAdmin',
        'action' => 'index',
        'roles' => array('a')
    ),
    'admin/users$' => array(
        'controller' => 'CUsers',
        'action' => 'index',
        'roles' => array('a')
    ),
    'admin/users/|[\d]+' => array(
        'controller' => 'CUsers',
        'action' => 'edit',
        'roles' => array('a')
    ),
    'products$' => array(
        'controller' => 'CProducts',
        'action' => 'index',
        'db' => TABLE_PRODUCTS
    ),
    'products/|[\w]+' => array(
        'controller' => 'CProducts',
        'action' => 'single_product',
        'db' => TABLE_PRODUCTS
    )
);
```

Правила записываются согласно синтаксису регулярных выражений кроме слеша '/' (я ето исправляю в коде роутера строчкой *$tmp = str_replace('/', '/', $key);*) для большей читабельности и лёгкости заполнения, и добавил условный символ разделитель '|' для отделения от функции контроллера дополнительных параметров, например http://SITE.COM/admin/users/11 - 11 здесь id юзера, admin контроллер, users - функция. Можно пойти дальше и передавать неограниченное количество параметров, но это согласно логике приложения. Если вмето integer 11 передать строку - получим 404.

2) Далее я создал класс Router который вызываю в index.php как ***new Router($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL']);*** - естественно вверху я уже подключил контроллеры. А вот и сам код класса Router:

```
class Router {

    public function __construct($request_uri)
    {
        global $routing;
        $request_uri = trim($request_uri, ' /');
        $className = '';
        $actionName = '';
        $route_data = array();
        //***
        $matches = array();
        $args = array();
        foreach ($routing as $key => $values)
        {
            $tmp = str_replace('/', '\/', $key);
            $tmp = str_replace('|', '', $tmp);
            //http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php
            if (preg_match_all('/' . $tmp . '/', $request_uri, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER) === 1)
            {
                $route_data = $values;
                $className = $route_data['controller'];
                $actionName = $route_data['action'];

                $tmp = explode('|', $key);
                if (isset($tmp[1]))
                {
                    $tmp = str_replace($tmp[0], '', $request_uri);
                    $tmp = trim($tmp, ' /');
                    if (!empty($tmp))
                    {
                        $args = explode('/', $tmp);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!empty($className) AND ! empty($actionName))
        {
            if (isset($route_data['roles']) AND ! empty($route_data['roles']))
            {
                $err_message = 'You have not access permissions OR your session expired!';
                $user_model = new MUsers();
                if ($user_model->is_user_logged_in())
                {
                    $user_data = $user_model->get_current_user();
                    if ($user_data)
                    {
                        if (!in_array($user_data['role'], $route_data['roles']))
                        {
                            die($err_message);
                        }
                    } else
                    {
                        die($err_message);
                    }
                } else
                {
                    die($err_message);
                }
            }
        }

        //+++

        if (class_exists($className))
        {
            $o = new $className();
            $o->{$actionName}($args);
        } else
        {
            //printf('Class %s doesn exists!', $className);
            echo render_html('front/404');            
        }
    }

}
```

**MUsers** - класс пользователей - модель - в которой проверяеться логирование и роль юзера, и если роль не входит в правила roles указанные в массив $routing юзер получит отказ в выдаче страницы

**render_html** - функция генерации html через вьюшку:

```
function render_html($pagepath, $data = array())
{
    $pagepath = str_replace(array('/', '\\'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $pagepath);
    if (is_array($data))
    {
        @extract($data);
    }
    ob_start();
    include(ABSPATH . 'templates/' . $pagepath . '.php');
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Я описал её в файле хелпера, на данном этапе не было надобности создания класса ради 1 этой функции так я не пишу CMS или что вроде етого - всё под проект, никаких лишних кодов и обёрток. Подключать контроллеры тоже лучше в роутинге, ето пока не сделал, так как если их штук 50, а нужен лишь один то нет смысла подключать кучу 49 ненужных контроллеров.