# PHP: Router: Привязать к массиву функции

Tags: php, router

Всем привет!
Я значит пишу роутер:

```
<?PHP
class router {

    public function Redirect($url, $permanent = false) {
        header('Location: ' . $url, true, $permanent ? 301 : 302);
        exit();
    }

    public function getRequestPath() {
        $path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
        return '/' . ltrim(str_replace('index.php', '', $path), '/');
    }

    public function getMethod(array $routes, $path) {
        foreach ($routes as $route => $method) {
            if ($path === $route) {
                return $this->routing($method);
            }
        }
        return $this->errorpage();
    }

    public function routing($method) {
        if ($method == 'main') {
            // Some code
            echo 'Main Page!!!';
        }
    }

    public function errorpage($error_page) {
        $smarty = new Smarty();
        $smarty->setTemplateDir('templates/');
        $smarty->setCompileDir('templates_c/');
        $smarty->setConfigDir('configs/');
        $smarty->setCacheDir('cache/');
        $smarty->assign('VERGEN',rand(20, 150000));

        $HttpStatus = $_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"];
        $httpc = array(400,401,403,404,500,503);

        if ($error_page == null) {
            if (in_array($HttpStatus, $httpc)) {
                $error_page = $HttpStatus;
            } else {
                $error_page = 404;
            }
        }

        if ($error_page == 400) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
            header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
            header("Status: 400 Bad Request");
            $title = "400 - Плохой запрос!";
            $title1 = "400";
            $reason = "Плохой запрос!<br>Через 15 секунд вы будете автоматически перенаправлены на главную страницу.";
        } else if ($error_page == 401) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
            header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
            header("Status: 401 Unauthorized");
            $title = "401 - Ошибка авторизации!";
            $title1 = "401";
            $reason = "Ошибка авторизации!<br>Через 15 секунд вы будете автоматически перенаправлены на главную страницу.";
        } else if ($error_page == 403) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
            header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
            header("Status: 403 Forbidden");
            $title = "403 - Запрещено!";
            $title1 = "403";
            $reason = "Вы попали на запрещённую страницу сайта!<br>Через 15 секунд вы будете автоматически перенаправлены на главную страницу.";
        } else if ($error_page == 404) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
            header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
            header("Status: 404 Not Found");
            $title = "404 - Нет такой страницы!";
            $title1 = "404";
            $reason = "Такой страницы не существует!<br>Через 15 секунд вы будете автоматически перенаправлены на главную страницу.";
        } else if ($error_page == 500) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
            header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
            header("Status: 500 Internal Server Error");
            $title = "500 - Внутренняя ошибка сервера!";
            $title1 = "500";
            $reason = "Внутренняя ошибка сервера!<br>Через 15 секунд вы будете автоматически перенаправлены на главную страницу.";
        } else if ($error_page == 503) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
            header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
            header('Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
            $title = "503 - Ведутся технические работы";
            $title1 = "503";
            $reason = "Ведутся технические работы!<br>По окончанию всех работ сайт снова заработает.<br>Приносим свои извинения за доставленные неудобства.";
        } else {
            $this->Redirect('/', false);
        }
        $smarty->assign('TITLE',$title);
        $smarty->assign('TITLE1',$title1);
        $smarty->assign('REASON',$reason);
        $smarty->display('global/error.tpl');
    }

    public function display($routes) {
        $path = $this->getRequestPath();
        $method = $this->getMethod($routes, $path);
        return $method;
    }
}
?>
```

Запускаю так:

```
$rout = new router();
$routes = [
    '/' => 'main'
];
$rout->display($routes);
```

Всё замечательно работает и удовлетворяет мои потребности, но! Мне постоянно приходится править класс роутера, это неудобно! Хочу от этого уйти но не придумал как. Допустим, я хочу реализовать страницы в бд, и чтобы мне их отобразить, мне нужно снова править роутер (функцию routing).

Как, допустим, сделать привязку к каждому значению массива функцию? Допустим, есть массив и к каждой строке уже из базы задавать что откуда вызвать?
Сделать другой многомерный массив? А там уже экшенами дёргать?
Вот я курил это но не сообразил как сделать...
[Как организовать Router php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/374867/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-router-php)

Comment: вы привели кучу кода про генерацию ошибок, но суть не понятна, что вы там вообще пишите в методе `routing` и постоянно  дописываете туда. Он у вас выполняет роль экшена контроллера что ли? дак это не хорошо. Где у вас тут парсинг url и ее сопоставление контроллеру/экшену, или у вас не mvc вообще?

Comment: Правильнее составить новую структуру файлов. Рекомендую переосмыслить правила построения вашего роутинга

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если для чисто изучения - [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) 
Если хотите выучить и понять, как лучше - смотрите уже давно реализованные роутеры

Если в Вашем случае, попробуем такой небольшой велосипед.
Нам потребуются конкретно методы `hasMethod` => `getMethod` => `invoke`

Общий принцип такой:

- Функция routing получает название метода
- Через ReflectionClass она вызывает
  этот метод, который по идее находится в классе, который отвечает за
  сами страницы

А вот так будет выглядеть пример ( все методы парсинга я убрал из класса Router и добавил класс Controller )

```
class Router {
    public function routing ( $method ) {
        $reflectClass = new \ReflectionClass( "Controller" );
        if ( $reflectClass->hasMethod( $method ) ) {
            $reflectMethod = $reflectClass->getMethod( $method );
            $className = $reflectClass->getName();
            echo $reflectMethod->invoke( new $className );
        }
    }
}


class Controller {

    public function main () {
        return "main";
    }

    public function test () {
        return "test";
    }
}

$get = ["main", "test"];

$router = new Router();
foreach ( $get as $route ) {
    $router->routing( $route );
    echo " ";
}

// выведет: main test
```

Проверить можно [тут](https://eval.in/1004988)

Это лишь самый простой, вялый и не проработанный пример, который просто показывает принцип. Нормальные конструкции уже будут включать в себя и автозагрузчики, и передачу аргументов, и более серьезные проверки и т.д.

ПыСы, необязательно использовать для этого ReflectionClass, однако он предоставляет удобный и более чем полный функционал для таких целей

Answer (score -1):

Подошёл с другой стороны. Использовал `call_user_func`. Удалил `routing` из-за ненадобности.

```
<?PHP
class router {

    public function Redirect($url, $permanent = false) {
        header('Location: ' . $url, true, $permanent ? 301 : 302);
        exit();
    }

    public function getRequestPath() {
        $path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
        return '/' . ltrim(str_replace('index.php', '', $path), '/');
    }

    public function getfuncuser(array $routes, $path) {
        foreach ($routes as $route => $funcuser) {
            if ($path === $route) {
                return call_user_func($funcuser);
            }
        }
        return $this->errorpage();
    }

    public function errorpage($error_page) {
        $smarty = new Smarty();
        $smarty->setTemplateDir('templates/');
        $smarty->setCompileDir('templates_c/');
        $smarty->setConfigDir('configs/');
        $smarty->setCacheDir('cache/');
        $smarty->assign('VERGEN',rand(20, 150000));

        $HttpStatus = $_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"];
        $httpc = array(400,401,403,404,500,503);

        if ($error_page == null) {
            if (in_array($HttpStatus, $httpc)) {
                $error_page = $HttpStatus;
            } else {
                $error_page = 404;
            }
        }

        if ($error_page == 400) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
            header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
            header("Status: 400 Bad Request");
            $title = "400 - Плохой запрос!";
            $title1 = "400";
            $reason = "Плохой запрос!<br>Через 15 секунд вы будете автоматически перенаправлены на главную страницу.";
        } else if ($error_page == 401) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
            header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
            header("Status: 401 Unauthorized");
            $title = "401 - Ошибка авторизации!";
            $title1 = "401";
            $reason = "Ошибка авторизации!<br>Через 15 секунд вы будете автоматически перенаправлены на главную страницу.";
        } else if ($error_page == 403) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
            header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
            header("Status: 403 Forbidden");
            $title = "403 - Запрещено!";
            $title1 = "403";
            $reason = "Вы попали на запрещённую страницу сайта!<br>Через 15 секунд вы будете автоматически перенаправлены на главную страницу.";
        } else if ($error_page == 404) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
            header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
            header("Status: 404 Not Found");
            $title = "404 - Нет такой страницы!";
            $title1 = "404";
            $reason = "Такой страницы не существует!<br>Через 15 секунд вы будете автоматически перенаправлены на главную страницу.";
        } else if ($error_page == 500) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
            header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
            header("Status: 500 Internal Server Error");
            $title = "500 - Внутренняя ошибка сервера!";
            $title1 = "500";
            $reason = "Внутренняя ошибка сервера!<br>Через 15 секунд вы будете автоматически перенаправлены на главную страницу.";
        } else if ($error_page == 503) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
            header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
            header('Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
            $title = "503 - Ведутся технические работы";
            $title1 = "503";
            $reason = "Ведутся технические работы!<br>По окончанию всех работ сайт снова заработает.<br>Приносим свои извинения за доставленные неудобства.";
        } else {
            $this->Redirect('https://allsvr.ru/', false);
        }
        $smarty->assign('TITLE',$title);
        $smarty->assign('TITLE1',$title1);
        $smarty->assign('REASON',$reason);
        $smarty->display('global/error.tpl');
        exit;
    }

    public function display($routes) {
        $path = $this->getRequestPath();
        $funcuser = $this->getfuncuser($routes, $path);
        return $funcuser;
    }
}
?>
```

Теперь всё работает как надо.

То есть мой роутер запускает нужную мне функцию.

```
function main() {
    echo "Hello World!";
}

$rout = new router();
$routes = [
    '/' => 'main'
];
$rout->display($routes);
```

При заходе на главную запустится `main` и выведет `Hello World!`.